# Color rows depending on another columns by numbers

Tags: excel, vba, background-color

I am trying to modify the below code.
Sheet from 1 to 8, maybe less.
Sheet 1 = Column A contain number, Column B contain numbers that group column A.
Column A   Column B
11200          3
11202          3
12500          4
12502          4
And more rows down, so even number in column B=color blue, odd number columnB= color green
Ineed to apply more colors, so I need iseven+1=color yellow, isodd+1=color brown.

```
    Sub Color()

Dim CvbRed, cYellow, cGreen, cBlue As Integer

For Each cell In Range("B5:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

 Select Case Color
 
Case IsEven
Range("A5:A").Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
        cRed = cRed + 1

Case IsOdd
Range("A5:A").Cells.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        cYellow = cYellow + 1
  
Case IsEven + 2
Range("A5:A").Cells.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        cGreen = cGreen + 1
    
Case IsOdd + 2
Range("A5:A").Cells.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        cBlue = cBlue + 1
    
    End Select
Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Please check the picture above in this post, Column A need only the colors, depending on when Column B has even, odd, even+1, odd+1.

Comment: Thank you so much CDP1802, That code will save a lot of time. Please check the picture above in this post, Column A need only the colors, depending on when Column B has even, odd, even+1, odd+1.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Mod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ColorMacro()

    Dim wb As Workbook, cell As Range, lastrow As Long
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim arColor ' odd-green, even-blue, odd+1-brown, even+1-yellow
    arColor = Array(RGB(128, 255, 128), _
              RGB(128, 128, 255), _
              RGB(200, 150, 100), _
              RGB(255, 255, 128))
     
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For n = 2 To wb.Sheets.Count
        With wb.Sheets(n)
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
                i = (cell.Value - 1) Mod 4
                cell.Offset(,-1).Interior.Color = arColor(i)
            Next
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```