# Inputbox Count rows and highlight by color

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count near 2.000 rows with numbers.

From the scratch, add more data from another workbook,  I have to Apply sort, format, filter and  print, and so on.

I need a code to performance the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTRHq.png)

In column A start row 1 until rows 145
Apply format color to every x rows = see the image. So 14 rows will have yellow, next 14 rows will have blue and so on. (number will always change)

InputBox to select x rows and colored, until we finished format color the numbers with the image above. Apply sheet1 until sheet go up...Sheet2...

The code below need to works with your code posted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim i, lastrow, code, rw As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
code = InputBox("Enter numbers of rows to color ", "Rows")
i = Range("A:A").Select

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7VTp.png)

Comment: So what have you tried? Doesn't seems like you have actually made any attempt in what you want to do in your question.

Comment: Thank you Raymond Wu for your replay. I just start with the code, I tried many times to change the code but I 'm not really  expert, I would really appreciate kindly give me a hand with this one.

Comment: Isn't this similar to your [previous question and an excellent answer was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862269/color-rows-depending-on-another-columns-by-numbers)?Why didn't you modify from that answer? @GoalExcel

Comment: I prefer to use different codes. This code need to define rows count depend on a group see image above.

Comment: I don't think your image is exactly clear in explaining anything. Same number = same group? You are the one asking the question so it is to **your** benefit if you explain things clearly and in details.

Comment: So what is x based on the image? What does all those numbers and color means? What is the group you are talking about? I suggest that you edit your question, give a small sample data and describe every single step of what the code should do based on the sample data. @GoalExcel

Comment: Due that numbers of rows always change, need to use inputbox, for select some rows, and format colors in different sheet 1 until sheet 8 or more.

Comment: So is the inputbox supposed to select the range with the numbers of rows for each group are or is it supposed to take in a numeric value for the number of rows to be colored for each a group?

Comment: Inputbox have to select range A1:A14 =follow  image above= 14 rows color yellow, go on. Rows are going to change in each shee1 until sheet 8, or less sheet or more.

Comment: We can put the image in B1, B2, B3 so on.. And use this value and color to select 14 rows in A1 start..until we reach with row A145.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify which column is your input, group are in each worksheet -You will have to adopt the code below and adjust accordingly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorByGroup()
    Const groupCol As Long = 5 'Column E
    Const groupStartRow As Long = 1
        
    Const inputCol As Long = 1 'Column A
    Const inputStartRow As Long = 5
    
    Dim colorArr As Variant
    'array of color to be used for highlight, add/remove as desired
    colorArr = Array(RGB(255, 230, 153), _
                    RGB(146, 208, 80), _
                    RGB(155, 194, 230), _
                    RGB(244, 176, 132))
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    
    '=== Get an array of the group values (excluding the last row as assumes that is the sum and is not part of the group)
    Dim groupLastRow As Long
    groupLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, groupCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim groupArr As Variant
    groupArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(groupStartRow, groupCol), ws.Cells(groupLastRow - 1, groupCol)).Value
        
    Dim inputRow As Long
    inputRow = inputStartRow
    
    Dim colorIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(groupArr, 1)
        'Get the color in array based on i
        colorIndex = i Mod (UBound(colorArr) + 1)
        
        ws.Cells(inputRow, inputCol).Resize(groupArr(i, 1)).Interior.Color = colorArr(colorIndex)
                
        inputRow = inputRow + groupArr(i, 1)
    Next i

    Erase groupArr
    Erase colorArr
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```